# Mysql CASE & SUM Cannot get the correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a calculation I am trying to run in the database rather than in php but I cannot get the right result out of it. It uses CASE and SUM because the calculations differ if there is a conversion factor involved.

The **saved_total** column is the correct total which is a stored value for comparison. The **mysql_cost** and **mysql_total_cost** columns are being calculated from the 'commodity_price' table and should match these - but are incorrect.

If I add a grouping of 'ri.preset_val' this gives me 4 rows - and the total of each pair of mysql_total_cost and mysql_cost columns would be correct if added together! (2nd table in snippet).

Tearing the little hair I have left out!

**There is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dda86/24)**

This is the query:

```
SELECT ri.recipe_id,rnr.recipe_name,rnr.qty_percentage, sum(ri.cost) as saved_total,

CASE
WHEN ri.quantity_unit=3 && ri.type='uom' THEN SUM(ROUND(

cp.cost*ri.qty

,2))
WHEN ri.type='auom' THEN SUM(ROUND(

(cp.cost / 1000 * cau.conversion_factor *ri.qty)

,2))
ELSE ROUND(SUM(

(cp.cost / 1000 * ri.qty * ri.preset_val))
,2) END AS mysql_total_cost,


CASE
WHEN ri.quantity_unit=3 && ri.type='uom' THEN ROUND(SUM(
rnr.qty_percentage
*
(cp.cost*ri.qty)
*.01)
,2)
WHEN ri.type='auom' THEN ROUND(SUM(
rnr.qty_percentage
*
(cp.cost / 1000 * cau.conversion_factor *ri.qty)
*.01
),2)
ELSE ROUND(SUM(
rnr.qty_percentage
*
(cp.cost / 1000 * ri.qty * ri.preset_val)*.01)
,2) END AS mysql_cost


FROM requisition_nested_recipe rnr 
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON ri.recipe_id=rnr.recipe_id 
LEFT JOIN commodity_price cp ON ri.price_id = cp.commodity_price_id
LEFT JOIN commodity_additional_units cau ON ri.cau_id = cau.cau_id
WHERE rnr.requisition_id=1 AND ri.recipe_id=rnr.recipe_id
GROUP BY ri.recipe_id
```

This is the ouput:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><table class="table">
<tbody><tr><th>recipe_name</th><th>qty_percentage</th><th>saved_total</th><th>mysql_total_cost</th><th>mysql_cost</th></tr>
<tr><td>Brioche</td><td>33.33</td><td>1.4</td><td>1.03</td><td>0.34</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cheesecake Cream</td><td>66.67</td><td>0.95</td><td>0.94</td><td>0.63</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="table"><tbody><tr><th>recipe_name</th><th>qty_percentage</th><th>saved_total</th><th>mysql_total_cost</th><th>mysql_cost</th></tr><tr><td>Brioche</td><td>33.33</td><td>1.01</td><td>1.01</td><td>0.34</td></tr><tr><td>Brioche</td><td>33.33</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.13</td></tr><tr><td>Cheesecake Cream</td><td>66.67</td><td>0.87</td><td>0.87</td><td>0.58</td></tr><tr><td>Cheesecake Cream</td><td>66.67</td><td>0.08</td><td>0.08</td><td>0.05</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

So, to explain a little further, we have 2 recipes in the nested_recipe table that we need to calculate the cost of x % of (qty_percentage). Each ingredient is stored in the recipe_ingredient table. The prices of the  commodities (ingredients) are stored in the commodity_price table. To complicate things some of the commodities are in different units of measure that require a conversion - which is where the commodity_additional_units table comes into play.

Note: The cost column in recipe_ingredient table is a stored value. We need to calculate it from the cost (effectively a basecost) of the commodity stored in the commodity_price table.

requisition_nested_recipe table

```
+----------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| requisition_id | recipe_id | recipe_name      | qty_percentage |
+----------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
|              1 |      3138 | Brioche          |          33.33 |
|              1 |      3140 | Cheesecake Cream |          66.67 |
+----------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
```

recipe_ingredient table

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+------+----------+--------+------------+------+
| recipe_id | commodity_id | cau_id | type | price_id | qty    | preset_val | cost |
+-----------+--------------+--------+------+----------+--------+------------+------+
|      3138 |     10000012 |      0 | uom  |     2152 | 350.00 |          1 | 0.27 |
|      3138 |       450526 |      0 | uom  |      605 |   5.00 |          1 | 0.00 |
|      3138 |       450644 |      0 | uom  |      619 |  35.00 |          1 | 0.06 |
|      3138 |       450908 |      0 | uom  |      718 |   7.00 |          1 | 0.10 |
|      3138 |       300160 |    201 | auom |      499 |   3.00 |          3 | 0.39 |
|      3138 |       300021 |      0 | uom  |      469 | 170.00 |          1 | 0.58 |
|      3140 |       300103 |      0 | uom  |      485 | 100.00 |          1 | 0.40 |
|      3140 |       450644 |      0 | uom  |      619 |  10.00 |          1 | 0.02 |
|      3140 |       450741 |      0 | uom  |      629 |   0.50 |          5 | 0.08 |
|      3140 |       300104 |      0 | uom  |      486 | 150.00 |          1 | 0.45 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+------+----------+--------+------------+------+
```

commodity_price table

```
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
| commodity_price_id | commodity_id | currency_id | cost  |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
|                469 |       300021 |           1 |  3.40 |
|                485 |       300103 |           1 |  4.00 |
|                486 |       300104 |           1 |  3.00 |
|                499 |       300160 |           1 |  2.25 |
|                605 |       450526 |           1 |  0.39 |
|                619 |       450644 |           1 |  1.60 |
|                629 |       450741 |           1 | 31.00 |
|                718 |       450908 |           1 | 14.83 |
|               1335 |       300021 |           2 |  4.08 |
|               1351 |       300103 |           2 |  4.80 |
|               1352 |       300104 |           2 |  3.60 |
|               1365 |       300160 |           2 |  2.70 |
|               1471 |       450526 |           2 |  0.47 |
|               1485 |       450644 |           2 |  1.92 |
|               1495 |       450741 |           2 | 37.20 |
|               1584 |       450908 |           2 | 17.80 |
|               2152 |     10000012 |           1 |  0.77 |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

Commodity_additional_units table

```
+--------+--------------+------+-------------------+
| cau_id | commodity_id | auom | conversion_factor |
+--------+--------------+------+-------------------+
|    201 |       300160 |    3 |          58.00000 |
+--------+--------------+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Your question describes that you have a problem.  But it doesn't explain the issue.  Sample data, desired results, and a simplified query would all help.

Comment: There is a fiddle linked and sample output data in the snippet already. I have tried to explain it a bit better in an edit. I will add some table data.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and should raise an exception. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, it does not error.

Comment: I've added ri.recipe_id to the select which gives the same result. I will look into GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` explodes the number of rows, then the `SUM` is done on this temp table; finally the `GROUP BY` shrinks the data back down.

This leads to `SUM` and `COUNT` to be bigger than they should be.

The 'fix' is to us the minimum number of `JOINs` when computing each aggregate.  This may involve multiple subqueries.

Comment: In this case the SUM(ri.cost) is correct, but the SUM() for mysql_total_cost and mysql_cost are lower than anticipated. If I explicitly check each commodity total using WHERE to check one by one - they are individually correct.

Comment: I should add, in the snippet results (and on the fiddle) the row for Cheesecake is correct.